# curl SOAP request

Tags: powershell, curl, soap

I have a question about `curl` and PowerShell.

I have installed git on my Server (Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise) and I call from PowerShell `git/bin/curl`.

```bsh
$tempFile = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName() | Rename-Item -NewName { $_ -replace 'tmp$', 'xml' } –PassThru
$soupRequestXML | Set-Content $tempFile -Encoding UTF8    

cd $env:temp
$cmd = "C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin\curl -X POST -H `'Content-type:text/xml;charset:UTF-8`' -d `@" + $tempFile.name  + " "+ $soapService
Invoke-Expression $cmd
```

where `$soupRequestXML` is my soap request.

The problem is, that PowerShell has some trouble to parse the `@` character.

This is the PowerShell Error:

> Invoke-Expression : Die Splat-Variable "@tmpCEA7" kann nicht erweitert werden. Splat-Variablen können nicht als Teil eines Eigenschafts- oder Arrayausdrucks verwendet werden. Weisen Sie das Ergebnis des Ausdrucks einer temporären Variable zu, und führen Sie stattdessen einen Splat-Vorgang für die temporäre Variable aus.

Sorry I know it is in German, but I work on a Server that is not mine. Like you can see I have already tried to escape the `@` character, but it's still not working.

I also tried to pass the string directly to `curl`:

```bsh
$cmd = "C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin\curl -X POST -H `'Content-type:text/xml;charset:UTF-8`' -d `'" + $(Get-Content $tempFile)  + "`' "+ $soapService
```

But then it seems that `curl` has some problem to parse it, so someone has an idea?

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: <soapenv
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: <soapenv
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: <com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: <arg0>xx<
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: <arg1>xxx<
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: <
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: <
```

This is my SoapRequest XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com=\"http://host...../">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <com:test>
      <arg0>xx/arg0>
      <arg1>xx</arg1>
    </com:test>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Why are you using `curl` instead of `Invoke-WebRequest`?

Comment: Because I'm a Java-Developer and I don't have much experience with Powershell?  And I also thought that this only works with Poweshell Version > 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of double quotes in your XML and using `Invoke-Expression` with a command string is messing things up.

For one thing, don't use `Inovoke-Expression` when you can use the call operator (`&`) instead. Gives you a lot less escaping headaches. Replace the double quotes in the XML string with single quotes to get them out of the way.

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin\curl" -X POST `
  -H 'Content-type:text/xml;charset:UTF-8' `
  -d "$((Get-Content $tempFile) -replace '"',"'")" $soapService
```

With that said, if you're using PowerShell anyway it'd make more sense to use [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx):

```
[xml]$data = Get-Content $tempFile
$headers = @{'SOAPAction' = '...'}
Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Uri $soapService -ContentType 'text/xml;charset="UTF-8"' -Headers $headers -Body $data
```

or (since you seem to be stuck with PowerShell v2) the [`System.Net.WebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

```
[xml]$data = Get-Content $tempFile

$req = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($soapService)
$req.Headers.Add('SOAPAction', '...')
$req.ContentType = 'text/xml;charset="utf-8"'
$req.Method = 'POST'

$stream = $req.GetRequestStream()
$data.Save($stream)
$stream.Close()

$rsp = $req.GetResponse()
$stream = $rsp.GetResponseStream()
[xml]$result = ([IO.StreamReader]$stream).ReadToEnd()
$stream.Close()
```

Comment: Perfect it works :-). I've changed to the standard soapRequest from PowerShell v2. @Ansgar Wiechers: Thx very much for your help